# Python urljoin not joining relative and absolute urls together correctly

Tags: python, url, join, urllib

I have these two urls:

```
absolute_url = 'https://ciechgroup.com/en/relacje-inwestorskie/reports/current-reports'
relative_url = 'en/relacje-inwestorskie/reports/current-reports/2018/242018/'
```

And I'd like to join them to create this:

```
https://ciechgroup.com/en/relacje-inwestorskie/reports/current-reports/2018/242018/
```

However, urljoin doesn't join the urls together correctly:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

urljoin(absolute_url, relative_url)

>> https://ciechgroup.com/en/relacje-inwestorskie/reports/en/relacje-inwestorskie/reports/current-reports/2018/242018/
```

Do you know how I can achieve this without duplicating part of the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urljoin` is doing what it's supposed to do. It's taking the "current path" of your absolute url (`/en/relacje-inwestorskie/reports/`) as the base to which your relative url will be "relative to". The result is indeed `/en/relacje-inwestorskie/reports/en/relacje-inwestorskie/reports/current-reports/2018/242018/`.

From your expected result, it seems that your `relative_url` is actually an absolute path, so you need to prepend `/` to it.

```
>>> absolute_url = 'https://ciechgroup.com/en/relacje-inwestorskie/reports/current-reports'
>>> relative_url = '/en/relacje-inwestorskie/reports/current-reports/2018/242018/'
>>> from urllib.parse import urljoin
>>> urljoin(absolute_url, relative_url)
'https://ciechgroup.com/en/relacje-inwestorskie/reports/current-reports/2018/242018/'
```

Comment: Thanks the the help!

Answer (score 3):

Prepend a `/` in your relative_url

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
absolute_url = 'https://ciechgroup.com/en/relacje-inwestorskie/reports/current-reports'
relative_url = '/en/relacje-inwestorskie/reports/current-reports/2018/242018/'
>>> urljoin(absolute_url, relative_url)
'https://ciechgroup.com/en/relacje-inwestorskie/reports/current-reports/2018/242018/'
```